# Do I need SSL Certificate for SQL Server and Web Server?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am currently developing a website in C#, It requires to send requests to remote SQL Server. 
I need to encrypt any communications from the client to the web server and to the SQL Server.

The SQL Server is currently used locally by another windows application, so the SQL server is being used locally and remotely.

So my concern is do I need to install cert for both servers ? If so will there be any connection problem between windows application and sql server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you would only need a certificate on your sql server 
use the encypt=yes option in your connection string on the web server.